# Расчёт центра объемной фигуры по серии 2D срезов

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

У меня на входе имеется 3-мерный массив, в котором каждый элемент является 2d изображением с маской, z координата - это количество срезов в данной серии, при этом сама фигура криволинейной формы.

Как рассчитать центр этой объемной фигуры ?

То есть как рассчитать центр фигуры по её срезам и выдать координату XY по картинке и Z по срезам (допустим они равномерно расположены).

[image: Что-то в таком духе(это срезы объемной фигуры.)]

Comment: @Xybyyn вам надо определить центр для каждого изображения? не общий центр?

Comment: @Александр, на выходе должен получиться  центр всей фигуры.

Comment: @Xybyyn как я понимаю, нижний рад - постороннее? работать мы будем с массивом бинарных масок?

Comment: @Александр, да, на входе получаем бинарные изображения(маски), идущие друг за другом.

Comment: @Xybyyn маски будут собраны в массив? идеал - 3-мерный массив np (преобразование можно добавить и в ответе, главное - договориться, в каком формате будут представлены маски)?

Comment: @Александр, На входе мы получаем 3-мерный массив(x,y,z), в котором каждый элемент представлен срезом изображения.

Comment: Уточните, что же на входе, 3-мерный массив изображений, или как на картинке полоска со срезами? (под вопросом, кнопка "править")

Comment: @ Kromster, спасибо, добавил.

Comment: @Xybyyn на выходе вы ожидаете последовательность из трёх элементов x, y, z  (тот самый центр)? как вам считать z? вы будете задавать какой-то шаг?

Comment: чем глубже копаю, тем обширнее тема, вам надо что-то вроде центроида трехмерного бинарного изображения, по аналогии с центроидом бинарного изображения (centroid of a binary image).

Comment: здесь показано как рассчитать [centroid of a binary image](https://robotclass.ru/tutorials/opencv-moments-color-object-search/)

Comment: там используются `cv.moments`

Comment: всё сильно зависит от ваших целей, как вы будете использовать эти данные, как правильно подойти к расчёту ..

Comment: https://aishack.in/tutorials/image-moments/ вот ещё немного полезной информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз бинаризация уже проведена (судя по верхнему ряду), остаётся вычислить центр масс по его определению, фактически выполнив интегрирование (приняв массу белой точки за 1)

```
m = 0
mx = 0
my = 0
mz = 0
Для каждого слоя с координатой z:
    Для всех y:
        Для всех х:
           if pt[y][x] белая:
                m += 1
                mx += x
                my += y
                mz += z
cx = mx / m
cy = my / m
cz = mz / m
```